# Avatar troubles rounded corners

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out what's the best method to do the following:
Let's say I have a circle with color x where I want to put an avatar in, my goal is to make the avatar image round too in order to make the result look a lot nicer.

I can do this with php-gd, but will have probably need to do a lot of calculations(unless I've missed out on some gd function), is there a better or faster way to tackle it eg css?

tia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I was you I would use CSS3 for simplicity. The below will turn the image into a circle and give it a 1px circle border.

```
div.avatar{
    width:30px; height:30px; border:solid 1px #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px; -moz-border-radius: 16px; border-radius: 16px;
}

div.avatar img{
    width:30px; height:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px;
}

<div class="avatar"><img src="" /></div>
```

- CSS3 isnt supported by old versions of IE

Comment: To save code, you could also just do the `div.avatar` css and then the html as `<div class="avatar" style="background: #FF000 url(/path/to/img.jpg) no-repeat center; text-indent:-50000em;">User name</div>` (Text replacement for screen readers)

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses everybody, too bad I can't split the right answer..Jleagle just came up with the fastest working example. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're actually better to use a bit of CSS trickery to do this. Basically you want to set up a transparent PNG positioned above the image, using it as a mask for the image.
For an example [check out this post about it](http://wegraphics.net/blog/articles/png-masking-how-to-dynamically-shape-any-image-on-your-website/).

I wouldn't recommend using a CSS3 solution (border-radius) without some kind of backup, as it's much less supported. But I guess if your okay with only having modern support then CSS3 would be the better option.

Comment: "much less supported"? You are talking about MS IE <= 8?

Comment: @feeela and older versions of other browsers. Considering the market share of IE7+8 alone is estimated to be at around 25%, I'd say it's worth providing a fallback.

Comment: Or you just have square pictures in those browsers, give a damn and promote updating to new software… *bigevilgrin*

Comment: I'm not saying sites need to look exactly the same. I'm saying that for the very little extra work involved in creating a PNG mask for this, it'd be worth doing it that way instead of CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be using simple CSS selectors:

```
<img class="avatar" src="" />
```

and in your CSS file:

```
.avatar {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Yup, it's that simple. Check out my Codepen example: http://codepen.io/usersnap/pen/udJgc